# creating graph-Spring mvc framework error did not find current representation

Tags: spring-mvc

while creating graphs in spring MVC on tomcat apache server it is shoving the error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

My controller class:

```
package in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.controllers;
import java.util.List;

import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData.KeyValue;
import in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.services.PieChartService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/piechart")
public class PieChartController {
@Autowired
private PieChartService pieChartService;



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String springMVC(ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<KeyValue> pieDataList = pieChartService.getPieChartData();
    modelMap.addAttribute("pieDataList", pieDataList);
    return "spring";
}

}
```

This is web.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Springgraphs</display-name>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener- 
class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- 
 class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>piechart.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <!-- spring end -->
 </web-app>
```

This is the dispatcher servlet code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.controllers, in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.daos, in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.services"></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" >
       </property>   
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">

 </property>
</bean>
```

This is the service interface:

```
  package in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.services;
  import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData.KeyValue;

 import java.util.List;
 public interface PieChartService {
List<KeyValue> getPieChartData();
}
```

service interface implement class:

```
 package in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.services;
 import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData.KeyValue;
import in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.daos.PieChartDao;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 public class PieChartServiceImpl implements PieChartService{
@Autowired
private PieChartDao pieChartDao;

public void setPieChartDao(PieChartDao pieChartDao) {
    this.pieChartDao = pieChartDao;
}

@Override
public List<KeyValue> getPieChartData() {
    return pieChartDao.getPieChartData();
}
}
```

DAO interface:

```
package in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.daos;
import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData.KeyValue;

import java.util.List;
public interface PieChartDao {
List<KeyValue> getPieChartData();
}
```

Dao implementation class:

```
   package in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.daos;
   import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData;
   import in.webtuts.google.chart.data.PieChartData.KeyValue;

   import java.util.List;

   public class PieChartDaoImpl implements PieChartDao{
    @Override
    public List<KeyValue> getPieChartData() {
    return PieChartData.getPieDataList();
    }
    }
```

This is the applicationContext.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

   <bean id="pieChartDao" 
   class="in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.daos.PieChartDaoImpl"></bean>


    <bean id="pieChartService"
    class="in.webtuts.google.chart.spring.services.PieChartServiceImpl">
    <property name="pieChartDao" ref="pieChartDao"></property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

This is the DATA class:

```
  package in.webtuts.google.chart.data;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class PieChartData {
  private static final List<KeyValue> pieDataList;

   static {
    pieDataList = new ArrayList<PieChartData.KeyValue>();
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("Russia", "17098242"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("Canada", "9984670"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("USA", "9826675"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("China", "9596961"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("Brazil", "8514877"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("Australia", "7741220"));
    pieDataList.add(new KeyValue("India", "3287263"));
    }

    public static List<KeyValue> getPieDataList() {
    return pieDataList;
    }

    public static class KeyValue {
    String key;
    String value;

    public KeyValue(String key, String value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    }
    }
```

This is the JSP file:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Google Chart - Servlet 3</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]
     });


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {


    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Country', 
    'Area(square km)'],
    <c:forEach items="${pieDataList}" var="entry">
      [ '${entry.key}', '${entry.value}' ],
      </c:forEach>
      ]);

     var options = {
        'title' : 'Area-wise Top Seven Countries in the World',
        is3D : true,
        pieSliceText: 'label',
        tooltip :  {showColorCode: true},
        'width' : 900,
        'height' : 500
    };


    var chart = new 
     google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div style="width: 600px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```